# Google Sheets: Transpose Form answers from the same row to rows/columns, keeping the first 2 columns fixed and the other columns variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Form whereby a customer can make multiple requests in one go, rather than using the "Submit another response" function, as this is preferential time wise.

Therefore the data formats across 1 row only as follows into the linked Google Sheet.

| Timestamp | Email Address | Question 1a | Question 1b | Question 1c | Question 2a | Question 2b | Question 2c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Abc@.com | 1a | 1b | 1c | 2a | 2b | 2c |
| 02 | Abc@.com | 1a | 1b | 1c |  |  |  |
| 03 | Xyz@.com | 1a | 1b | 1c | 2a | 2b | 2c |

I am trying to work out a method, ideally using Google Apps Script or otherwise using formulas, to transpose the data, repeating the timestamp and email address but otherwise "chunking" out the submissions in columns 3, 4, 5 and then 6, 7, 8 into separate rows, for example.

| Timestamp | Email Address | Attribute | Attribute | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Abc@.com | 1a | 1b | 1c |
| 01 | Abc@.com | 2a | 2a | 2c |
| 02 | Abc@.com | 1a | 1b | 1c |
| 03 | Xyz@.com | 1a | 1b | 1c |
| 03 | Xyz@.com | 2a | 2b | 2c |

It must iterate down every row so therefore any new submissions must be appended to the existing list in the Target Sheet, or the whole lot can be redone each day on a timed trigger to transpose the list out of hours.

Example sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sMMdl26HS2Bfsb4iYLfOQt6ydMW5qVKXyy3UJ-tEdaU/edit?usp=sharing

We have an existing VBA solution but need to transfer to Cloud based using Google Sheets.

Any support or ideas would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only 2 sets of answers

```
=sort(query({'Source Data'!A:B,'Source Data'!C:H;'Source Data'!A:B,'Source Data'!J:O},"select * where Col3 is not null",0))
```

for more, add `'Source Data'!A:B,'Source Data'!xxx:yyy`

Comment: Noticed that the formula won't work if I include all potential ranges (in this case, 10 sections of answers) but seems like a dummy row of data suffices as a workaround or at least 1 set of answers needs to fill the maximum amount of columns possible. Aside from that, this does exactly what I need it to. Added sorting parameters for the Timestamp to keep it chronological.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I haven't tested 10 sets of answers. I did not know this limit.

Comment: Yeah apologies I should have indicated in the example. Regardless, I followed your adding via `'Source Data'!A:B,'Source Data'!xxx:yyy` to look at all possible columns that make up the sections of the form. Thank you.